# Numbering alphabets according to group type

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 groups of species in an excel sheet. `Cat`, `Dog` ,`Human`. The names of individuals in each group is postfixed by an alphabet. e.g `Cat A` , `Dog B` etc.

I would like to rename them according to the numeric order. For example, if `Cat A',`Cat B' were the only entries, then output would be 'Cat 1', Cat 2'. Similarly, if `Cat C',`Cat D' were the only entries, then output would still be 'Cat 1', Cat 2'.

Below is a table that should cover all the scenarios. I could technically accomplish this by having a huge `=if` formula but was hoping for a more dynamic method if I should add anymore items into the `Group'

```
Order:
A
B
C
D
E
F

Group:
Cat
Dog
Human


    A       B
1   Name:   Output:
2   Cat A   Cat 1
3   Dog B   Dog 1
4   Cat C   Cat 3
5   Cat B   Cat 2
6   Dog D   Dog 2
7   Human D Human 2
8   Human A Human 1
9   Dog E   Dog 3
```

Comment: This might be hard to swing with pure Excel.  Do you have access to a relational database?

Comment: By relational database you mean by SQL query type right? Then nope, the name entries come to me in excel sheets as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this (Enter in B2 provided A1 and B1 are Headers and A2 and below has the data)

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT($A2,FIND(" ",$A2)-1)," ",COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,LEFT($A2,FIND(" ",$A2)-1)&"*"))
```

But this formula requires the data to be sorted if that is fine

Comment: Ahh, was hoping for a non-sorted answer. But the formula works great. Thanks!!